# Django forms.py initialized wrongly?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-modeltranslation

I have a django view communicate the user's preferred locale to a form in forms.py. However, that form seems to get initialized before I even call it.

Class SurveyForm() seems to load *before* my call from views.py and even *before* the SurveyForms() **init** function becomes active.

Here is the code:

```
class SurveyForm(forms.Form):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    Q1 = questions.get(identifier='Q1')
    question1 = forms.CharField(required=False, label=Q1.name)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        translation.activate('nl')
```

When I put `translation.activate('nl')` in the `SurveyForm` class, it does work.
When I put `translation.activate('nl')` in the `__init__`, or in `views.py`, it does not work. How can this be changed?

Note: I use modeltranslation, so `Q1.name` will get the Dutch translation when Dutch language is active.

Comment: Please confirm that I've edited the code correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything at class level is executed when the class is defined, on first import. You already know how to do things at instantation time - by doing it in the `__init__` method.

It's not clear from your question what `Q1` is. Is it a field? If so you can add it to `self.fields`; otherwise just set it directly on `self`.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    translation.activate('nl')
    super(SurveyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['Q1'] = ...
    # or
    self.Q1 = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the code for clarity.

Comment: 1. self.fields['Q1'] gives error: 'SurveyForm' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: 2. self.Q1: works, but I get in the template: <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x0438F390>

Comment: @Jdruiter `self.fields` will work after you've called `super().__init__()`.

Comment: Awesomeness. Thanks.